# managing env variables in Go libraries

Tags: go

I am writing a library in Go. There are several configurable values and I am looking to understand some good ways to set these values. I have considered following options:

1. use os.Getenv() to get values of env variables wherever they are to be used. Drawback is reading same env variable multiple times.
2. Create a config file, read all config variables, and pass the config struct around. I do not intend to pass such struct around in multiple places. There are files which need a static value determined at startup.
3. Use init() function; afaik this is not recommended, at least multiple init are not recommended.

Any more recommendations on a simpler and cleaner approach?

Comment: _"Use init() function; afaik this is not recommended"_ It's recommended if it's sensible. Multiple `init()` functions are also totally fine if sensible. Also the result of `os.Getenv()` can be stored in a variable so you do not need to call it ever time you need it.

Comment: For os.Getenv(), it's my 2nd approach which you have recommended. As for init(), people often say that with multiple init() determining order can be a challenge and so should be avoided. But if there is no dependence on execution order, it does make sense to use it like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Reading settings from config files or the environment should be done at startup. If I understand correctly, your question is about how these values should be injected into other packages.

Here is a few ideas.

1. A global config package that contains all settings. The settings are read on startup and are then globally available here. **Pro:** all settings available, everywhere. **Con:** Settings are mutable, consider making them read only by adding functions and not exporting the settings object.
2. After reading in the settings on startup, inject them into each package. A package that requires a setting can have a public `Init(...)` function that accepts all necessary settings. Don't use `init()`. **Pro:** no big config structs, only necessary settings. **Con:** globals all over the place, can become messy very fast, you can forget to call `Init()`, etc.
3. Require settings: To avoid the chaos involving globals described above, just require settings in all code that uses them: For a function, accept the setting as an argument. If you have a struct with methods, even better: Make the setting a field of the struct that needs to be defined. If you have a constructor, have that constructor accept the setting. **Pro:** No globals, dependencies on settings are clear. **Con:** It might not be obvious which values are application settings right away, until you trace back their origin.

Number 3 is my favorite method since imho it makes it much more clear where
settings are coming from and how they are being used.